calculate the input value and update 3 results when click calculate button with JavaScript
I have 4 calculations that I have set up to spit out results when an integer 1-100 is typed into the input. right now, the values automatically update as I am typing, but I want them to wait until the calculate button is clicked. I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong, or what I am missing.


let phoneOutput = document.getElementById("rc-phone");
let carOutput = document.getElementById("rc-car");
let trashOutput = document.getElementById("rc-trash");
let monthlyCost = document.getElementById("monthly-cost");
let input = document.getElementById("customPercent");
let ggrResults = document.querySelector("#customPercent");

ggrResults.addEventListener('input', e => adjustData(e.target.value)) // had to add in .value in order to extract the text from the input
const adjustData = (a) => {
//   convert value from input text to number in order to calculate
  const numberConvert = Number(a);
  const decimal = numberConvert/100;
  const monthlyCostFormula = (8000 * decimal) * (.026/12);
  const trashBagFormula = 243 * decimal;
  const milesDrivenFormula = 14294 * decimal;
  const phonesChargedFormula = 368949 * decimal;
  monthlyCost.innerHTML = monthlyCostFormula.toFixed(2);
  trashOutput.innerHTML = Math.round(trashBagFormula);
  carOutput.innerHTML = Math.round(milesDrivenFormula);
  phoneOutput.innerHTML = Math.round(phonesChargedFormula);
}
<form method="post">
  <input id="customPercent"  type="text" placeholder="custom" />
  <button type="submit" onclick="return(adjustData());" id="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
<div>
  <h6>Equal to Removing</h6>
  <span style="font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif;" id="rc-trash">100</span><br>
  <span class="green-text small-txt">Trash Bags of Waste from the Environment</span>
</div>
<div>    
  <h6>Equal to offsetting</h6>
  <span style="font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif;" id="rc-car">20</span><br>
  <span class="green-text small-txt">Gas-Powered Miles Driven</span>
</div>
<div>
  <h6>Equal to offsetting</h6>
  <span style="font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif;" id="rc-phone">500</span><br>
  <span class="green-text small-txt">Smartphones Charged</span>
</div>
<div>
  <h4 class="heading-4">Estimated Monthly Cost <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This will have an explanation"><i class="fa fa-info-circle gray"></i></a></h4>
  <span style="font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif;">$<span id="monthly-cost">15.00</span></span>
  <h5>per month</h5>   
</div>




I think you need to remove then the event listener and keep the onclick function of the button. Also then change const numberConvert = Number(a) to  let numberConvert = ggrResults.value. In the onclick="return(adjustData()) you don't need here the return

Did you mean something like this? Without the event listener and firing calculation only on click?


const adjustData = () => {
const input = document.getElementById("customPercent");
const phoneOutput = document.getElementById("rc-phone");
const carOutput = document.getElementById("rc-car");
const trashOutput = document.getElementById("rc-trash");
const monthlyCost = document.getElementById("monthly-cost");
const ggrResults = document.querySelector("#customPercent");

  // convert value from input text to number in order to calculate
  const numberConvert = Number(input.value);
  const decimal = numberConvert/100;
  const monthlyCostFormula = (8000 * decimal) * (.026/12);
  const trashBagFormula = 243 * decimal;
  const milesDrivenFormula = 14294 * decimal;
  const phonesChargedFormula = 368949 * decimal;
  monthlyCost.innerHTML = monthlyCostFormula.toFixed(2);
  trashOutput.innerHTML = Math.round(trashBagFormula);
  carOutput.innerHTML = Math.round(milesDrivenFormula);
  phoneOutput.innerHTML = Math.round(phonesChargedFormula);
}
<form method="post">
  <input id="customPercent"  type="text" placeholder="custom" />
  <button type="button" onclick="adjustData();" id="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
<div>
  <h6>Equal to Removing</h6>
  <span style="font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif;" id="rc-trash">100</span><br>
  <span class="green-text small-txt">Trash Bags of Waste from the Environment</span>
</div>
<div>    
  <h6>Equal to offsetting</h6>
  <span style="font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif;" id="rc-car">20</span><br>
  <span class="green-text small-txt">Gas-Powered Miles Driven</span>
</div>
<div>
  <h6>Equal to offsetting</h6>
  <span style="font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif;" id="rc-phone">500</span><br>
  <span class="green-text small-txt">Smartphones Charged</span>
</div>
<div>
  <h4 class="heading-4">Estimated Monthly Cost <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This will have an explanation"><i class="fa fa-info-circle gray"></i></a></h4>
  <span style="font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif;">$<span id="monthly-cost">15.00</span></span>
  <h5>per month</h5>   
</div>




This solution also works localized, but when I add it to my project, it just gives me four 0s in the results, no matter what number (1-100) I enter.

@notAGoodDeveloper there were couple of issues. Change the 'submit' to 'button' and read the values on click.

something like that ?


const
  myForm      = document.querySelector('#my_form')  
, phoneOutput = document.querySelector('#rc-phone')
, carOutput   = document.querySelector('#rc-car')
, trashOutput = document.querySelector('#rc-trash')
, monthlyCost = document.querySelector('#monthly-cost')
  ;
myForm.addEventListener('submit', e =>
  { 
  e.preventDefault();  // disable form submission (and page reload)

  const
    decimal              = myForm.customPercent.valueAsNumber / 100 // get value
  , monthlyCostFormula   = (8000 * decimal) * (.026/12)
  , trashBagFormula      =   243 * decimal
  , milesDrivenFormula   = 14294 * decimal 
  , phonesChargedFormula = 368949 * decimal
    ;
  monthlyCost.textContent = monthlyCostFormula.toFixed(2);
  trashOutput.textContent = Math.round(trashBagFormula);
  carOutput.textContent   = Math.round(milesDrivenFormula);
  phoneOutput.textContent = Math.round(phonesChargedFormula);
  }
)
div > span:first-of-type {
  font-size   : 28px; 
  font-weight : bold; 
  font-family : sans-serif;
  }
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SnH5WK+bZxgPHs44uWIX+LLJAJ9/2PkPKZ5QiAj6Ta86w+fsb2TkcmfRyVX3pBnMFcV7oQPJkl9QevSCWr3W6A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<form id="my_form">
  <input name="customPercent"  type="number" placeholder="custom" min="0" max="100" required >
  <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
<div>
  <h6>Equal to Removing</h6>
  <span id="rc-trash">100</span><br>
  <span class="green-text small-txt">Trash Bags of Waste from the Environment</span>
</div>
<div>    
  <h6>Equal to offsetting</h6>
  <span id="rc-car">20</span><br>
  <span class="green-text small-txt">Gas-Powered Miles Driven</span>
</div>
<div>
  <h6>Equal to offsetting</h6>
  <span id="rc-phone">500</span><br>
  <span class="green-text small-txt">Smartphones Charged</span>
</div>
<div>
  <h4 class="heading-4">
    Estimated Monthly Cost 
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This will have an explanation">
      <i class="fa fa-info-circle gray"></i>
    </a>
  </h4>
  <span>$<span id="monthly-cost">15.00</span></span>
  <h5>per month</h5>   
</div>




If I understand it right:
<form method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return false">
To prevent page refresh/redirection: "#" is a empty anchor and "return false" is a js soltution.
ggrResults.addEventListener('input', e => adjustData(e.target.value))
Quoted out.
<button type="submit" onclick="adjustData(document.getElementById('customPercent').value)";" id="submit">Calculate</button>
onclick calls the function and pass the value by get the input object's value by the id "customPercent".


let phoneOutput = document.getElementById("rc-phone");
let carOutput = document.getElementById("rc-car");
let trashOutput = document.getElementById("rc-trash");
let monthlyCost = document.getElementById("monthly-cost");
let input = document.getElementById("customPercent");
let ggrResults = document.querySelector("#customPercent");

// had to add in .value in order to extract the text from the input
// ggrResults.addEventListener('input', e => adjustData(e.target.value))
const adjustData = (a) => {
//   convert value from input text to number in order to calculate
  const numberConvert = Number(a);
  const decimal = numberConvert/100;
  const monthlyCostFormula = (8000 * decimal) * (.026/12);
  const trashBagFormula = 243 * decimal;
  const milesDrivenFormula = 14294 * decimal;
  const phonesChargedFormula = 368949 * decimal;
  monthlyCost.innerHTML = monthlyCostFormula.toFixed(2);
  trashOutput.innerHTML = Math.round(trashBagFormula);
  carOutput.innerHTML = Math.round(milesDrivenFormula);
  phoneOutput.innerHTML = Math.round(phonesChargedFormula);
}
<form method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return false">
  <input id="customPercent"  type="text" placeholder="custom" />
  <button type="submit" onclick="adjustData(document.getElementById('customPercent').value)";" id="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
<div>
  <h6>Equal to Removing</h6>
  <span style="font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif;" id="rc-trash">100</span><br>
  <span class="green-text small-txt">Trash Bags of Waste from the Environment</span>
</div>
<div>    
  <h6>Equal to offsetting</h6>
  <span style="font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif;" id="rc-car">20</span><br>
  <span class="green-text small-txt">Gas-Powered Miles Driven</span>
</div>
<div>
  <h6>Equal to offsetting</h6>
  <span style="font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif;" id="rc-phone">500</span><br>
  <span class="green-text small-txt">Smartphones Charged</span>
</div>
<div>
  <h4 class="heading-4">Estimated Monthly Cost <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This will have an explanation"><i class="fa fa-info-circle gray"></i></a></h4>
  <span style="font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif;">$<span id="monthly-cost">15.00</span></span>
  <h5>per month</h5>   
</div>




This runs correctly here but when I add the updated form code and comment out that line in my JS on my project, I get 0 in all the results when I select calculate.

What doctype is ur project? Just html?
